# Random meta field from specific custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am loading single images into a post and calling their source from my custom post type template `single-photo.php` :

```
src: "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'single_photo', true); ?>"
```

I want to pull an image from a random post only from that post type [PHOTO].  I know the url will be `mysite.com/photo/-random-photo-`, how could I grab a radom meta field?

Answer (score 0):

You could pull it directly form the database:

```
global $wpdb;

$random_photo = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key like 'single_photo' ORDER BY RAND()");
```